# Shortest path(s) in linked graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I'm working on applying graphing algorithms to a possibly non-standard application.  I have graphs that are linked together and am trying to find the top K shortest node-disjoint paths through them.  Hopefully I can explain this:  As an example, say I have two fairly simple graphs with a start and end. In my case, the graphs go through stages (left to right) and both have the same number of stages.  I can use Dijkstra or something to find the shortest path in each, but they are linked together such that some nodes in the first graph are linked to a matching node in the second graph.  Selecting one requires selecting the other.  My first idea was to merge the two graphs into one with all possible combinations getting a node.  So if at a certain stage in graph one the nodes are A,B,C and graph two had D,E,F, and if C and F are linked, the options are AD,AE,BD,BE,CF.  This works fine for finding the single best path.  The problem comes when I apply Suurballe's algorithm to find the K best node disjoint paths because two node disjoint paths could, for example, select AD and AE.  These are node disjoint in the combined graph, but not in the original problem (they share A).  Is there any prior art in this type of problem, or can anyone think of a straightforward solution?

Picture example:  Find K minimum cost paths (sum of both paths) through these two graphs under the constraint that if you pick the colored node in one graph you have to pick the same color node in the other.  Edges are weighted even though not shown.

[image]

Another example (example 2) in response to the answer below:
[image]

Comment: A diagram would go a long way to helping explain your scenario...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about 'prior art' in this domain, but I guess I can think of a 'straightforward solution'.

1. Find the best path in the Graph 1 (the first graph)
   separately, as shown in the 'Picture Example'. Compute the cost
   function for this path, say CF1.
2. Find the number of coloured nodes in Graph 1's optimal path.
3. For all coloured nodes in Graph 1, remove all alternate connection
   from Graph 2, i.e, ensure that a path in Graph 2 has to go through
   the coloured nodes used in Graph 1.
4. Find the optimal path in Graph 2 and compute its cost function, say
   CF2.
5. Compute CF1 + CF2
6. Repeat steps 1 to 5, but this time start with Graph 2 and then match
   Graph 1's coloured nodes with Graph 2's initial optimal path.

The lowest value of CF1+CF2 would give you a set of feasible path.

Basically, you plan the path for one of the graph and get the other graph to comply with its set of linked nodes and the check the combined cost function. Then repeat for the other graph. Find the best combination that works.

In general, for n graphs, you would have to perform n^2 shortest path computations, which is obviously very bad. But it should work, as a naive idea.

++++++++++++++++++++

Here's my modified version of the previous algorithm for weighted graph:

Assumption : We are working with 'n' graphs, all of them are weighted and all of them contains equal and fixed number of 'stages'.

All the starting nodes are described as S1, S2, S3…. Sn.
All the terminal nodes are described as e1, e2, e3….. en.

1. Initiate an empty priority queue (PQ) [preferably using binary/fibonacci min heap] that will contain paths (collection of nodes) and their corresponding priority will be denoted by the cumulative sum of their **path weights**]
2. Insert all starting nodes - S1, S2, S3…. Sn into PQ, the priority of each individual nodes set to zero.
3. Pop the path with the lowest weight (say it belongs to graph number 'k') and expand it's children. Let there be 'p' children nodes. [If there are no more stages to expand into, delete that path from the priority queue. This way, if the total size of the queue becomes zero, then there are no feasible path between S and e]
4. For i = 1 to n for all i not equal to k, repeat:

   4a. Check which of the p paths are **feasible** in the remaining (n-1) graphs.

   4b. Insert all the **feasible** paths to PQ (after computing their priorities).

   4c. If one of the **feasible** paths end up in ek : then mark that path as 'PathOptimal' and go to 5.
           else : go to 3.
5. For i = 1 to n for all i not equal to k : find the corresponding paths in each graph against 'PathOptimal' and report them as the output.

Here, the concept of ***path weights*** has to be implemented correctly. 
Path weight will be equal to: sum of weights of the edges contained in that path + sum of weights of edges contained in all sibling paths in the remaining (n-1) graph.

The concept of ***feasibility*** will be your business rule, i.e if a children is a coloured node, the corresponding children of the previous path in all other (n-1) graphs has to be of the same colour. If it not a coloured node, it's sibling children will have to be non-coloured.

[Please let me know if you figure out any obvious flaw in the algorithm since I just made it up. Also, since this has been heavily borrowed from Dijkstra's, let me know if you could figure a method for speeding this up.]

*P.S:- However, I must mention that given the scope of your problem, I'd rather use genetic algorithm for solving this than going by a deterministic method.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My typical cases will have 3-4 graphs, so I'm not worried about the computational cost.  I uploaded another image of two graphs that seems to break your approach though.  The top graph chooses the path indicated with cost of 2, but if I force graph two through those nodes it has to pick the very high cost diagonal paths.  The graphs are symmetric, so the same problem will happen when processing in reverse.  The jointly optimal answer would be to go down the middle in both and avoid the colored nodes.  Did I misunderstand your approach?

Comment: I'm sorry I neglected to notice that the graph was weighted. Moreover, I realised, the algorithm I proposed finds a feasible path but not the optimal path. I will edit my response for a weighted graph. Check this and let me know.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks reasonable.  I've been putting together a vectorized version of Dijkstra that I think is largely the same.  With a lot of nodes, the run time gets out of hand pretty quickly.  I'm going to look closely at your version and see if there may be computational advantages over what I have.

Comment: Thanks. It is very likely that there are some loop holes in what I proposed. Please bring to my attention if you happen to notice any. I'll let you know if I figure out something faster, all these variants of Dijkstra's are indeed very expensive.